# Minimal Python build for my application's scripting needs?

Tags: python, scripting, python-embedding

what are your advices on building a very minimalistic version of Python(2.x) for my application's scripting needs.

My main motive here is to keep the foot print (both memory and disk wise) as low as possible so that my native application won't suffer from any major performance hit. Even the Python DLL size is in consideration because of the possibility of increasing boot up time of my application.

Can we go as low as [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) or other lightweight solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried [Tiny Python](http://www.tinypy.org/)?

Answer (score -1):

You can use only the dll